# How to use glob notation in a Java-style comment?

Tags: comments

This is kind of silly, but it's tripping me up and googling has failed me.

Consider the following:

```
/*
Example commandline parameters for this class:
--job-name MyJob
--output-path /path/to/output
--input-data /path/to/data/2018/08/*.csv
*/

object DataProcessor {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // code here
  }
}
```

The general intent is to use glob notation in a long comment; the above shows an example of why you might want to do that.  The problem is that the `/*` in `/path/to/data/2018/08/*.csv` turns everything into a comment.

Is there a slick way of "capturing" the `/*`, short of just adding another `*/` at the end?  I tried enclosing the comment with `/**` and `**/` like in doc strings, but the result is the same.

Comment: As far as I know, Java does not support nested comments, so there should be no problem with your code. However, it seems that your code is not valid Java, so your entire question about "Java-style comments" is completely irrelevant. Maybe, whatever other language you are *actually* using has nested comments? In that case, you will have to look into that language's manual to figure out how to escape comment delimiters.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The specific example that I included happens to be Scala, which uses the same comment rules as Java.  I observed the same behavior in an actual Java class, so I could replace the example if it would make you happier.

Comment: I just tested our example in Java, and it works just fine, because Java does not have nested comments and thus doesn't care what you put in your comment (unless it is an end-of-comment delimiter, of course). In Scala, it does not work, precisely because Scala does *not* have the "same comment rules as Java", since it has nested comments (which Java does not have) and thus the `/*` starts a second, nested, inner comment.